# Extract a specific character in between braces using R

Tags: r, regex

based on the following string

```
{EP03-C18} - {EP03-C19}
```

I am able to select the values btw the braces by using `\{(.*?)\}`
but how can I select only the `-`

in order to get string like `{EP03C18} - {EP03C19}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your strings have a well balanced amount of unnested `{...}`, you may use

```
s = "{EP03-C18} - {EP03-C19}"
gsub("-(?=[^{}]*})", "", s, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "{EP03C18} - {EP03C19}"
```

The `-(?=[^{}]*})` pattern matches a `-` that is followed with 0+ chars other than `{` and `}` and then followed with `}`. Since `(?=...)` is a lookahead the text matched is not added to the match value and you may use the regex to remove any amount of `-` inside `{...}`.

In case you have messier strings with many amount of unpaired `{` and `}` it is safer to use `gsubfn`:

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("{[^{}]+}", ~ gsub("-","",x,fixed=TRUE), s)
## => [1] "{EP03C18} - {EP03C19}"
```

**Details**

- `{` - matches `{`
- `[^{}]+` - 1 or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}`
- `gsub("-","",x,fixed=TRUE)` - removes all `-` inside the match.

Answer (score 2):

You could look for dashes within braces using lookaheads:

```
gsub("-(?=[^{}]*})", "", "{EP03-C18} - {EP03-C19}", perl=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
[1] "{EP03C18} - {EP03C19}"
```

However this assumes that all braces are balanced.

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/YWA5c6/1)**

Breakdown:

- `-` Match a dash
- `(?=` Start of positive lookahead

  - `[^{}]*}` If it meets up to a closing brace (without jumping over braces)
- `)` End of lookahead

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `(.*?{[^-]+)-([^-]+}.*?)`

To match every thing except the hyphen between the `{` and `}`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vu8qMp/1)

**Output**

```
{EP03C18} - {EP03C19}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search with the following regex and replace with an empty string.

```
(?<=\{\w+)-
```

It uses a positive lookbehind to ensure that the - character is after an opening curly brace.

If the regex package you are using doesn't support lookbehinds you could search with the following regex and replace with capture group 1.

```
(\{\w+)-
```

Comment: The second one works if you do this: `gsub("(\\{\\w+)-", "\\1", "{EP03-C18} - {EP03-C19}")` . The first one, i.e. `gsub("(?<=\\{\\w+)-", "", "{EP03-C18} - {EP03-C19}", perl = TRUE)
` gives an error complaining that the lookbehind is not fixed length.